# Solve a system of equations for positive ($x$, $y$, $z$)

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I arrived at the system of equations

$$(3+2z)x=3(1-xy)$$
$$(3+7z)y=4(1-xy)$$
$$3y-x+z(y-x)=2xy$$

while working on a geometric problem, with $x$, $y$ and $z$ representing segment lengths of a quadrilateral configuration. The system is inherently quartic. Given its non-standard appearance, I am not sure yet how to rearrange the pieces, which would lead to the solutions smoothly. A math tool I have spills out $(\frac12, \frac13, 1)$, without indicating how.

Before resorting to brute-force substitution, I would like to have a shot at anyone who may have expertise, or just happens to be conversant in such systems.

Comment: I would subtract $4$ times the first from $3$ times the second to get $0$ on the right, then solve the resulting equation for one of the variables.  That gets us to two equations in two unknowns.  It looks like you can then solve one for another variable.  You will get a messy set of fractions that I think you can clear to get a high order polynomial in one variable.  Now use the rational root theorem and you will find the root.  I haven't tried it, which is why this is not an answer.

Comment: Please do not shoot me for asking this question. Do you need an exact solution or an approximate solution? It looks like your best shot here is an iteration procedure  in numerical mathematics.

Comment: @YNK - Not at all. I know of the exact algebraic solution as mentioned in the post; like to know how.

Comment: @Quanto: if you eliminate $x y$ from the equations, you get $$38 x=2025 y^3-1980 y^2+1116 y-208 \\ 405 y^4-585 y^3+408 y^2-164 y=-26 \\ 247 z=-9720 y^3+10530 y^2-6360 y+1557$$ Notice that the second one is only an equation in $y$, which can be solved (there are two real solutions). Now that you have $y$, you can find $x$ in the first and then you can find $z$ in the third.

Comment: @Moo This should be an answer, if you will show how to arrive at these three equations.

Comment: @Quanto: The approach is to use Groebner basis and arrive at what I showed earlier $$38 x=2025 y^3-1980 y^2+1116 y-208 = 0 \\ 405 y^4-585 y^3+408 y^2-164 y=-26 \\ 247 z=-9720 y^3+10530 y^2-6360 y+1557$$ Now solve for each variable. There are two real results.

Comment: "Groebner basis" is the key word to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
\begin{cases}
(3+2z)x&=3(1-xy)
,\\
(3+7z)y&=4(1-xy)
,\\
3y-x+z(y-x)&=2xy
.
\end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Rearranging the system \eqref{1} as

\begin{align} 
\begin{cases}
\phantom{-}3xy+2zx &= 3-3x
,\\
\phantom{-}4xy+7yz &= 4-3y
,\\
-2xy+yz-zx &=x-3y,
\end{cases}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

we can express $xy,yz,zx$ in terms of $x,y$:

\begin{align} 
15xy &= \phantom{-}7x+36y-13
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
15yz &= -4x-27y+16
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
5zx &= -11x-18y+14
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Equation \eqref{3} gives $y$ in terms of $x$:

\begin{align} 
y &= \frac{7x-13}{3(5x-12)}
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

$z$ in terms of $x$
can be found from
equations \eqref{4} and \eqref{6}:

\begin{align}
z &= -\frac{4x^2-13x+15}{7x-13}
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

Equations \eqref{5}, \eqref{6} and \eqref{7} combined 
result in

\begin{align}
-\frac{2(2x-1)(5x^3-45x^2+127x-117)}{(7x-13)(5x-12)}
&=0
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}

which gives two real solutions for $x$:
\begin{align}
x_1&=\tfrac12
,\\
x_2&=
3+\tfrac1{15}\sqrt[3]{2025+15\sqrt{10545}}
+\frac 8{\sqrt[3]{2025+15\sqrt{10545}}}
\approx 4.54212431
.
\end{align}

Corresponding pairs of $y$ and $z$ are
\begin{align}
y_1&=\tfrac13
,\\
y_2&\approx 0.58492933
,\\
z_1&=1
,\\
z_2&\approx -2.047152
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Moo's comments. Therefore, all credit due for it should be given to Moo. However, I am taking responsibility for the text that appears below. Those who are not in the know can read about the $\bf{Gr\ddot{o} bner\space Basis}$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroebnerBasis.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).

All three equations of the equivalence system provided by Moo are correct and have the same collection of roots as the system posted by Quanto. As mentioned by Moo, it has 2 real roots and 2 complex roots. The two real roots are given below.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    x_1=\frac{1}{2} & \space & x_2=4.542124309455065516 \\
    y_1=\frac{1}{3} & \space & y_2=0.584929333410679641 \\
    z_1=1 & \space & z_2=-2.04715204771556650 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Quanto has mentioned in his post that $x, y$ and $z$ represent segment lengths of a quadrilateral configuration, which cropped up in a problem in geometry. Therefore, I think it is safe to assume that $x, y, z\ge 0$. If I am right, as par as Quanto's requirement is concerned, there is only one valid set of solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $z$ all three equations, after elimination we get

$$
\cases{
8 x+\frac{21}{x}-21 y-\frac{8}{y}-15=0\\
\frac{7 (x-1) x}{x-y}-9 x+\frac{2}{y}+9=0
}
$$

A plot shows the real solutions

[image]